# ggmap heatmap without colors

Tags: r, ggmap

I am having troubles with a heatmap visualization using ggmap library.

This is my data 'heatmap_df'

```
contributor_id  contb_receipt_amt   longitude   latitude
CODY, ERIN BUFFALO Clinton, Hillary Rodham  302 -78.8779    42.91766
LIEBER, MICHAEL NEW HYDE PARK Sanders, Bernard  150 -73.67895   40.7429
KERELCHUK, JAMES EAST AURORA Clinton, Hillary Rodham    350 -78.59804   42.77086
LIEBSON, AVRAM HECTOR Sanders, Bernard  300 -76.86246   42.5215
```

And this is the code with which I am trying to visualize the monetary amounts, with the longitude and latitude information.

```
NYMap = get_map(location = "New York", zoom = 11)
gg <- ggmap(NYMap, extent = "device")
gg <- gg + stat_density2d(data=heatmap_df, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, fill=..level.., alpha=..level..), geom="polygon",  position = "identity", contour = TRUE, n = 100)
gg <- gg + geom_density2d(data = heatmap_df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), size = 0.01)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") 
gg <- gg + scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)

gg
```

The result I get is the following, without any colored heatmap. You can only see the blue lines, but without the heatmap colors.
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I just tried running the rows displayed in the above table and I get the correct result. However when I run the full dataset, I get the wrong output. Does this library crash, if there are too many data points? I have 321.886 rows.

EDIT2:
I am trying to visualise the monetary amounts here, but currently the heatmap is counting simply the number of rows and not displaying the monetary amounts. What should I do?

Thanks a lot for your help and best regards

Comment: The code works on my R 3.4.1 with ggmap 2.6.1. See here: https://imgur.com/a/NlivJ

Comment: Strange!  Have you changed the code in any way? I see you have a different zoom level..

Comment: Yes, I changed zoom level because the 4 points in your `heatmap_df` are outside the area of your map

Comment: It makes sense, thanks a lot. I also re-ran the dataset with exactly the table info which i pasted there, and i get the same output. However my entire dataset has 321.886 rows. Could this be the reason why I get the wrong output?

Comment: The large number of rows should not be a problem. Anyway, try with subsets of increasing dimensions (100,1000,10000) and see what happens.

Comment: I just did that. It works with 10 rows, but it fails already at 20.

Comment: Also, I just noticed. I am trying to visualise the monetary amounts here, but currently the heatmap is counting simply the number of rows and not displaying the monetary amounts. What should i do?